# How to make Android studio stop to creating svn related files automatically in my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Just now my Android studio popup a dialog tell me someting about subversion issue, I didn't read it very carefully and click the Ok button, bad thing happens, Android studio create lots of svn related files and folders as below in every modules of my project.

```
> auth
> svn.simple
> svn.ssl.client-passphrase
> svn.ssl.server
> svn.username
> config
> README.txt
> servers
```

it does influence my project compilation, how can I recover my Android studio? I don't want to install my AS again. Many thanks!

Comment: Finally, I deleted the settings file of my Android Studio (C:\Users\dell-it\.AndroidStudio2.2), now this problem was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable version control system for your project in Android Studio by following these steps:

- Go to Android Studio preferences
- Select **Version Control** from the menu
  [image]
- Click on your project from the list
  [image]
- Click on the **-** button on the bottom of the list to remove
  [image]